# Kendo grid custom order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid what needs to be ordered in a custom way. I need two items at the top, then the others in alphabetical order.

Where I call the function:

```
var result = GetSelectMunkaTargyaResult(request, munkatargyaList, munkatargyaDataSourceResult);
```

In "GetSelectedMunkaTargyaResult" everything is fine, I orderd the elements in my wanted way, then at the return line it orders it alphabetically again.

```
private DataSourceResult GetSelectMunkaTargyaResult([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<MunkaTargya> munkaTargyaList = null, DataSourceResult dataSourceResult = null)
{
    ....
    return res.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

What should I do with the result to show it up on the grid the right order?

Comment: Have you looked at the custom server binding [example](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customserverbinding) from Telerik?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably reordered client-side by the grid.

You can either clear the grid filters before returning the data:

```
private DataSourceResult GetSelectMunkaTargyaResult([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<MunkaTargya> munkaTargyaList = null, DataSourceResult dataSourceResult = null)
{
    ....
    request.Filters.Clear();
    return res.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

Or you can return a new DataSourceResult:

```
private DataSourceResult GetSelectMunkaTargyaResult([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<MunkaTargya> munkaTargyaList = null, DataSourceResult dataSourceResult = null)
{
    ....
    return new DataSourceResult
    {
        Data = res,
        Total = res.Count()
    };
}
```